# I'm not able call the Listener Class,Whenever I tried to call Listener class it's Showing Errors

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm not able call the Listener Class,Whenever I tried to call Listener class it's Showing Errors

1. [I'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl6wV.png)

**Source Code**

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import StreamListener
import json
import twitter_credentials
import sys
import csv

auth =tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.consumer_key,twitter_credentials.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.access_token,twitter_credentials.access_token_secret)

api =tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication OK")
except:
    print("Error during authentication")


tweets =api.search_tweets(q="Python",lang="en")
#api.search_tweets(q="Python",lang="en",rpp=100)
for tweet in tweets:
    USER =tweet.user.name
    RETWEETS =tweet.retweet_count
    CREATED =tweet.created_at
    TEXT =tweet.text
    SOURCE =tweet.source
    print(USER +" | "+TEXT+" | "+str(RETWEETS)+ " | "+SOURCE)

class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __int__(self,passed_api):
        self.api =passed_api
        self.me= api.me()

    def on_status(self,tweet):
        USER = tweet.user.name
        RETWEETS = tweet.retweet_count
        CREATED = tweet.created_at
        TEXT = tweet.text
        SOURCE = tweet.source
        print(USER + " | " + TEXT + " | " + str(RETWEETS) + " | " + SOURCE)
        file =open("C:\\Users\\kishan chand\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\results\\tweets_extract.csv","a")
        output1 =USER+" | "+TEXT+" | "+str(RETWEETS)+" | "+SOURCE+ '\n'
        file.write(output1)
        file.close()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    tweets_listene =listener()
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.consumer_key, 
    twitter_credentials.consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.access_token, 
    twitter_credentials.access_token_secret)
    stream =tweepy.Stream(auth,twitter_credentials.access_token, 
    twitter_credentials.access_token_secret,tweets_listene)
    stream.filter(track =["India","Python"])
```

Basically,I'm trying to access the Stream Tweets with the help of Inherited StreamListener Class But I'm not able to call the Listener Class

Comment: The full error message is not shown in the image provided

Comment: Also remember to preview your question before posting for any formatting mistakes. Some code is unformatted text and some unformatted texts are in code blocks. You don't have to post an image with traceback as you can copy and paste the text directly into a code block